# Is it possible to have strides > 1 in conjunction with dilation rate > 1 in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use strides > 1 in conjunction with dilation rate > 1 in Keras, but I'm facing trouble. I have written the following code in TensorFlow.Keras

```
class Resnet_block(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, c, k, str, d):
    super(Resnet_block, self).__init__()
    keep_prob_=0.5
    inputs = Input(shape=(3000, 1))
    #convolution layer 1
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(c, k, strides=str, activation=None, padding='same', dilation_rate=d)(inputs)
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(conv1)
    conv1=tf.keras.activations.relu(conv1, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0)
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(conv1)
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(c, k, strides=str, activation=None, padding='same', dilation_rate=d)(conv1)
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(conv1)
    conv1=tf.keras.activations.relu(conv1, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0)
    conv1=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(conv1)
    self.ResnetBlock=tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv1)
    self.ResnetBlock.summary()
    #plot_model(self.CrossModel_Attention_out, to_file='self.CrossModel_Attention_out.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
 def call(self, inp, training=False):
   x = self.ResnetBlock(inp)
   return x

 Resnet_block1=Resnet_block(32, 3, 5, 1)
 Resnet_block2=Resnet_block(64, 3, 3, 2)
 Resnet_block3=Resnet_block(128, 3, 2, 4)
 Resnet_block4=Resnet_block(512, 3, 1, 8)
```

Getting the following error

```
ValueError: strides > 1 not supported in conjunction with dilation_rate > 1
```

I want to implement a representation learning model proposed in the paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.03352
[Model for representation learning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNPCh.png)
Please help me.

Comment: I really don't know what else to add to that error message? It's very clear.

Comment: Wanted to do this as well. Is there any reason this wasn’t implemented in keras?

Comment: Thanx #xdurch0, I have reframed the question please look into it.

Comment: @Chandra, Dilation basically means to leave out features (tokens or pixels) in between two features which will be convolved together. If you keep both dilation_rate and strides greater than 1 then some features will never be taken into account which is illegal. Thanks!